# How to pretty output of grep for searching within markdown files?

Tags: grep, markdown

I have a knowledge base (aka Zettelkasten) of markdown files. And I use searching with the next command `grep -irn 'search request' *.md`. All works fine.

But I'd like see output with the title of the file and sub header of the found string.

The sample

#### file.md

```
1 # Title
2
3 ## Subtitle
4
5 yada-yada
```

#### Output

```bash
> grep -irn 'yada' *.md

< file.md:5:Title:Subtitle:yada-yada
```

Can I do this with `grep` without multiple search in the file?

An analogue of [recall](https://www.lesbonscomptes.com/recoll/pages/index-recoll.html) for terminal would be ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, grep can't do that.  However, you could easily write your own custom search tool with awk or perl.  e.g.

```
find ./ -name '*.md' -exec awk -v search="yada-yada" '
  /^# /  { title=$0;    sub(/^# /,"",title)     };
  /^## / { subtitle=$0; sub(/^## /,"",subtitle) };
  $0 ~ search { printf "%s:%i:%s:%s:%s\n", FILENAME,FNR,title,subtitle,$0 }' {} +
```

This is a very primitive example, and could be customised to suit your exact needs, and otherwise greatly improved.  It should probably be wrapped in a shell script so you can have something like `-v search="$1"` rather than hard-coding it to `"yada-yada"`.

Here's a slightly better version, in perl.  This one doesn't require `find` (it uses perl's own [File::Find](https://perldoc.perl.org/File::Find) module instead) and is possibly easier to extend with better option handling (e.g. you could support searching multiple directories similar to `find`, or add `-i` or `-v` options for case-insensitivity or to invert the match, same as grep and some other programs):

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use File::Find;

# Very primitive argument handling, should use Getopt::Long or
# one of the other Getopt::* modules
my $path   = shift;    # first arg is dir to search, e.g. './'
my $search = shift;    # second arg is regex to search for

find({ wanted => \&wanted, no_chdir => 1}, $path);

sub wanted {
  # This uses \z in the regex rather than just $ because
  # filenames can contain newlines.
  next unless (-f $File::Find::name && /\.md\z/s);
  
  # open the file and "grep" it.
  open(my $fh, "<", $File::Find::name) || warn "couldn't open $File::Find::name: $!\n";
  
  my $title    = '';
  my $subtitle = '';
  
  while(<$fh>) {
    chomp;
    
    if (/^# /) {
      ($title = $_) =~ s/^# //;
    
    } elsif (/^## /) { 
      ($subtitle = $_) =~ s/^## //;
    
    } elsif (/$search/) {
      printf "%s:%i:%s:%s:%s\n", $File::Find::name, $., $title, $subtitle, $_;
      
      # uncomment the next line if you want only the first match in
      # any given file (i.e. same as '-m 1' with grep):
      # close $fh;
    }
  };
  close($fh);
}
```

Sample run:

```
$ ./grep-md.pl ./ yada-yada
./file.md:5:Title:Subtitle:yada-yada
./file2.md:5:Another Title:And Another Subtitle:yada-yada
./sub/dir/several/levels/deep/file3.md:5:Third Title:File Three Subtitle:yada-yada
```

BTW, this could also be written to use `find ... -exec` to find the files rather than doing it with File::Find, and would probably be better if it did....I mostly wrote it this way to show multiple different ways of achieving the same end goal.